# Error when i try to deserialise from url in c#

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a method to deserialise from an url and output the title lets say but i keep on get an error saying

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
> current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API.Entities.MessageDetail]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Status', line 1, position 12.

My method is:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

            var json_data = client.DownloadString("https:url-to-json.net");

            var messagesFromUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MessageDetail>>(json_data);
            
            foreach(var data in messagesFromUrl ) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(data.Title);
            }

            return NoContent();
```

and my model is:

```
public class MessageDetail
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }
        public string CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CreateBy { get; set; }
        public string DeepLinkAction { get; set; }
        public int ImportanceLevel { get; set; }
    }

    public class Content
    {
        public List<MessageDetail> MessageDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Content Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Json data

```
{
    "Status": 200,
    "Content": {
        "MessageDetails": [
            {
                "Title": "Emitere Factura",
                "MessageBody": "Factura ANB a fost emisa",
                "CreateDate": "2020-12-03 16:00:00",
                "CreateBy": "System",
                "DeepLinkAction": "Open invoice history scren",
                "ImportanceLevel": 2
            },
            {
                "Title": "Transmitere index",
                "MessageBody": "Sunteti in perioada de autocitire index",
                "CreateDate": "2020-12-03 16:00:00",
                "CreateBy": "System",
                "DeepLinkAction": "Opens the index transmission screen",
                "ImportanceLevel": 2
            },
            {
                "Title": "Analiza Apa",
                "MessageBody": "S-a transmis raportul de analiza apa pe email.",
                "CreateDate": "2020-12-03 16:00:00",
                "CreateBy": "System",
                "DeepLinkAction": "Download invoice",
                "ImportanceLevel": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize to the root object then access the Message Details.

```
var messagesFromUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json_data).Content.MessageDetails ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Net.Http` `HttpClient` class instead of `WebClient`
and `System.Text.Json` instead of Newtonsoft:

```
static async Task GetMessagesDetailsAsync() 
    {
        string url = @"https://...";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient() {BaseAddress = new Uri(url)};

        var request = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        {
            var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var messagesList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MessageDetail>>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions());
            foreach (var message in messagesList)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(message.MessageBody);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Also, I think the Url is broken.